# JQuery Plugin (datatables) with Webpack and Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am trying to use datatables JQuery plugin with webpack and typescript. I already have JQuery up and running together with typings (intelliSense works), for datatables I have the intelliSense only, but after webpack build when I run the app the code fails when it comes to $('#id').dataTable() line.

`app.js:43Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function`

I am not able to figure out how to attach this pluggin correctly, can anyone please help me?

The webpack.config.js is as follows;
https://gist.github.com/marcingolenia/2fa78ed2cd42f9294da5edd22d351245

I hope this line will solve the problem;

```
{ test: require.resolve("dataTables.net"), loader: "imports?define=>false,$=jquery"},
```

as the doc of import loader says;

> There are many modules that check for a define function before using
>   CommonJS. Since webpack is capable of both, they default to AMD in
>   this case, which can be a problem if the implementation is quirky.

datatables provides both, so I wanted to disable AMD using define=>false as mentioned here
https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/32542/datatables-and-webpack

Now I'm stuck :(

Comment: Have you installed the jquery datatables typings?

Comment: Yes, the typings are there so the intellSense for $(...).dataTable is working well and typescript compiler do not show any erros.
this comes from my typings;
    `"jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160316155526",
    "jquery.datatables": "registry:dt/jquery.datatables#1.9.4+20160317120654"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are almost there!

Make sure both `datatables.net` and `datatables.net-dt` installed via NPM:

```
npm install datatables.net datatables.net-dt --save-dev
```

in your entry file `./src/main.js` write:

```
require( 'datatables.net' )( window, $ )
require( 'datatables.net-dt' )( window, $ )
```

after that, any code logic of following format `$(...).DataTable` will work as the examples shown on the DataTables' homepage.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you input! I will try this tomorrow!

Answer (score 5):

Disabling AMD seems to be the answer. Many of the solutions I found weren't working for me.

The simplest way to disable AMD is to add the following rule to your webpack config(webpack 2+)

```
module: {
    rules: [
        { parser: { amd: false } }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Disabling AMD solve this issue for me.
Here is how to disable AMD if you are using Webpack Encore in Symfony 4:

```
var config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();

// disable amd, for datatable
config.module.rules.unshift({
  parser: {
    amd: false
  }
});

module.exports = config;
```